# Buttons over Mapview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am creating an OSMdroid mapview in my MapActivity.java and I want to add buttons & pop-ups - I only know how this is done in .xml but since this MapView is not using any .xml I am puzzled how I can place (image)buttons within my java code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Setup base map
    final RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);

    CloudmadeUtil.retrieveCloudmadeKey(getApplicationContext());

    final MapView osmv = new MapView(this, 256);

    myMapController = osmv.getController();  

    rl.addView(osmv, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    osmv.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    osmv.setMultiTouchControls(true);

    myLocationoverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, osmv);

//*snip* setup of map, mapcontrollers, tiles etc...
    osmv.getOverlays().add(tilesOverlay);
    osmv.getOverlays().add(myLocationoverlay);  

    this.setContentView(rl);
}
```

edit:
I am talking about a button like

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/map_goto_location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/goto_location"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:id="@+id/goto_location" />
```

Comment: Since you're adding the `MapView` to a `RelativeLayout`, simply add any other UI elements to this same container. Just make sure to add those after adding the `MapView` so that they get drawn on top. You can either set up all the UI elements in code, or declare them in xml and use a `LayoutInflater` to inflate them. Also, don't forget to add them after creating/inflating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of MH I found out how to programatically add an ImageButton to my code as below:

```
    ImageButton goto_location = new ImageButton(this);
    goto_location.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showMylocation();
        }           
    });

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40);
    params.rightMargin = 10;
    params.topMargin = 10;
    rl.addView(goto_location, params);
```

If anyone can hint me on some good tutorials/examples on customizing the button and on programmatically adding UI elements I would be very happy.

Comment: It is also possible to define this button in your layout XML. Simply create a RelativeLayout and add osmdroid MapView and your button(s).